# VBScript CreateObject with parameters

Tags: .net, vbscript, createobject

I'm trying to open a Windows Form in VBS and having some difficulty :-(

This line works ok (I think):

```
Set frmPopup = CreateObject("System.Windows.Forms.Form")
```

But the following fails on the first line with: Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'System.Drawing.Size'

```
    Set frmPopup.Size = CreateObject("System.Drawing.Size")
    frmPopup.Size.Width = cmintPSPFormWidth
    frmPopup.Size.Height = intPopupHeight
```

I guess that's because System.Drawing.Size needs the Height and Width parameters specified in the call?

The www talks about using:

```
Set frmPopup.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1,2)
```

But this gives me: Variable is undefined: 'System'.

I've done a regasm on System.Windows.Forms.dll and System.Drawing.dll from my .NET 4 installation folder but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Size is a value type, you can't create an object of it.  You are not supposed to get this far anyway, Form is not registered as a progid.  You must have done some bone-chilling things to your registry.  You'll need to write this off as an option, write a wrapper in C# or vb.net instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size is a method, not a ProgID.  You would probably need something like this:

```
Set frmPopup = CreateObject("System.Windows.Forms.Form")
Set frmDrwg = CreateObject("System.Drawing")
frmDrwg.Size 1, 2
```

But you must keep in mind that not all .NET object can be instantiated properly from VBS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't get it to work, so I'll stick with my PowerSmell solution :-(